# Visualise word2vec generated from gensim using t-sne

Tags: scikit-learn, data-visualization, gensim, word2vec

I have trained a doc2vec and corresponding word2vec on my own corpus using gensim. I want to visualise the word2vec using t-sne with the words. As in, each dot in the figure has the "word" also with it.

I looked at a similar question here : [t-sne on word2vec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40581010/how-to-run-tsne-on-word2vec-created-from-gensim)

Following it, I have this code :

import gensim
import gensim.models as g

```
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

modelPath="/Users/tarun/Desktop/PE/doc2vec/model3_100_newCorpus60_1min_6window_100trainEpoch.bin"
model = g.Doc2Vec.load(modelPath)

X = model[model.wv.vocab]
print len(X)
print X[0]
tsne = TSNE(n_components=2)
X_tsne = tsne.fit_transform(X[:1000,:])

plt.scatter(X_tsne[:, 0], X_tsne[:, 1])
plt.show()
```

This gives a figure with dots but no words. That is I don't know which dot is representative of which word. How can I display the word with the dot?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Two parts to the answer: how to get the word labels, and how to plot the labels on a scatterplot.

**Word labels in gensim's word2vec**

`model.wv.vocab` is a dict of {word: object of numeric vector}. To load the data into `X` for t-SNE, I made one change.

```
vocab = list(model.wv.key_to_index)
X = model.wv[vocab]
```

This accomplishes two things: (1) it gets you a standalone `vocab` list for the final dataframe to plot, and (2) when you index `model`, you can be sure that you know the order of the words.

Proceed as before with

```
tsne = TSNE(n_components=2)
X_tsne = tsne.fit_transform(X)
```

Now let's put `X_tsne` together with the `vocab` list. This is easy with pandas, so `import pandas as pd` if you don't have that yet.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(X_tsne, index=vocab, columns=['x', 'y'])
```

The vocab words are the *indices* of the dataframe now.

I don't have your dataset, but in the [other SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40581010/how-to-run-tsne-on-word2vec-created-from-gensim) you mentioned, an example `df` that uses sklearn's newsgroups would look something like

```
                        x             y
politics    -1.524653e+20 -1.113538e+20
worry        2.065890e+19  1.403432e+20
mu          -1.333273e+21 -5.648459e+20
format      -4.780181e+19  2.397271e+19
recommended  8.694375e+20  1.358602e+21
arguing     -4.903531e+19  4.734511e+20
or          -3.658189e+19 -1.088200e+20
above        1.126082e+19 -4.933230e+19
```

**Scatterplot**

I like the object-oriented approach to matplotlib, so this starts out a little different.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

ax.scatter(df['x'], df['y'])
```

Lastly, the `annotate` method will label coordinates. The first two arguments are the text label and the 2-tuple. Using `iterrows()`, this can be very succinct:

```
for word, pos in df.iterrows():
    ax.annotate(word, pos)
```

[Thanks to Ricardo in the comments for this suggestion.]

Then do `plt.show()` or `fig.savefig()`. Depending on your data, you'll probably have to mess with `ax.set_xlim` and `ax.set_ylim` to see into a dense cloud. This is the newsgroup example without any tweaking:

[image: scatterplot]

You can modify dot size, color, etc., too. Happy fine-tuning!

Comment: Great work! I suggest this code simplification: `df = pd.DataFrame(X2, vocab, ['x', 'y'])` and then `for word, pos in df.iterrows(): plt.annotate(word, pos)`. i.e. use the words as the index. You can get rid of the `concat` and other lines.

Comment: Made your two changes: `vocab` as df index and the `iterrows` simplification. Thanks, @RicardoCruz!

Comment: @NielsJoaquin, what are the changes we should do for visualizing only the similar words of a particular word?

Comment: `AttributeError: The vocab attribute was removed from KeyedVector in Gensim 4.0.0.
Use KeyedVector's .key_to_index dict, .index_to_key list, and methods .get_vecattr(key, attr) and .set_vecattr(key, attr, new_val) instead.`

Answer (score 0):

With the following, you can convert your model to a TSV and then use [this page](https://projector.tensorflow.org/) for visualization.

```
with open(self.word_tensors_TSV, 'bw') as file_vector, open(self.word_meta_TSV, 'bw') as file_metadata:
    for word in model.wv.vocab:
        file_metadata.write((word + '\n').encode('utf-8', errors='replace'))
        vector_row = '\t'.join(str(x) for x in model[word])
        file_vector.write((vector_row + '\n').encode('utf-8', errors='replace'))
```

:)