# Is there are standard for annotating text with NLP concepts

Tags: stanford-nlp, opennlp

I was thinking to develop a service which can enrich arbitrary text with several NLP based concepts, such as POS tagging or word2vec vectors.

It should later be extended as well to ontologies.

I was wondering if there exist some standards how to "express" different "representations" of text in form of "tokens", "lemmas" or ontologies.

I googled quite a while to find something, but was not successful.

Maybe somebody here could give me some hints.

Answer (score 0):

Not certain to understand what you mean by "representations", but maybe T-SNE is something you might want to look at.

For example : http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/tsnejs/wordvecs.html

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40581010/how-to-run-tsne-on-word2vec-created-from-gensim) stackoverflow post gives a basic example using gensim & TSNE in python

Answer (score 0):

I found the UIMA(http://uima.apache.org/) standard which is able to express arbitrary "annotations" of text.
So this allows to express:
 - lemmas
 - tokens
 - word2vec
 - concepts

Answer (score 0):

DKPro Core provides a unified [UIMA](http://uima.apache.org/) based typesystem which expresses language uniformly. They provide several wrappers for different NLP frameworks in order to exchange them easily.

Take a look at [their typesystem](https://dkpro.github.io/dkpro-core/releases/1.9.0/docs/typesystem-reference.html). For example, DKPro Core provides a type for lemma, token, POS, named entity, etc.